# Can the Proximal Operator Have Discontinuity?

Tags: convex-analysis, proximal-operators

The proximal operator is defined as:
$\operatorname{prox}_{\sigma f}(y) = \arg \min_x (f(x) + \frac{1}{2 \sigma} \|x - y\|^2_2), \sigma > 0$.

I was wondering about whether the proximal operator is always continuous or not. My intuition says not, but I can't find any example where it is the case. Any help?

If the proximal operator is always a continuous function, how can I prove?

Comment: The proximal operator is set-valued map generally.  What  do you mean by it's continuity ?

Comment: If I plot the values of the proximal operator, is it possible that it is a discontinuous graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$ f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 0& x \neq 0 & \\ 
 -1& x =0 & 
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Take $\sigma = \frac{1}{2}  $  then  the value of proximal map is  $$P(y)  =\left\{\begin{matrix}
 0& y \neq 0 & \\ 
 -1& y =0 & 
\end{matrix}\right. $$ which is a discontinuous map.

Answer (score 3):

As Red shoes pointed out, they are not always continuous. However, if $f$ maps from a real Hilbert space to $]-\infty,+\infty]$, is:

- Not identically $+\infty$,
- Convex, and
- lower-semicontinuous,

then its proximal operator is always firmly nonexpansive, hence it is $1$-Lipschitz continuous. See also http://proximity-operator.net/proximityoperator.html and its references

Comment: This. Most of the time when we talk about the proximal operator it is in the context of convex functions, so this should be part of an accepted answer.